# How to Determine if Street Changes

Tags: android, geocoding

I am executing the following code:

```
public static int c;
public static boolean flag = false;
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Geocoder geocode;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocode = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault());
    try{
        addresses = geocode.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        StN.setText(address.toString());

        /* if(streetChanges){
            c = 0;
            flag = false;
        }

        if(flag == false){
            //do something
            flag = true;
        } */

    }
}
```

The problem i am facing is how to determine if the street changes !?

Any ideas.

Comment: save last address, check if `current_address != last_address`.. Since i don't know what getAddressLine return, this method return the current street right?

Comment: yes getAddressLine return the current street name depending on the device's latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!address.equals(lastAddress))
{
    c = 0;
    flag = false;

    lastAddress = address;
}
```

Inside

```
lastAddress
```

you store your last address, if onLocationChanged is called and the street is changed address and lastAddress have a different value, the block is called. I added c = 0; and flag = false; because in your comment you do this. Remove everything you don't need, just keep

```
lastAddress = address
```

Add

```
private String lastAddress; // Make it static if you need
```

below

```
public static boolean flag = false;
```

This should do what you want.

Ah,

```
StN.setText(address.toString());
```

address is already a string:

```
StN.setText(address);
```

Comment: Thanks marco, i can't thank you enough you saved my time, it's working great, Thanks alot.